# Wordpress mod_rewrite with page + get-parameter

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm having a little Problem with mod_rewrite in combination with wordpress :(

This is my htaccess:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

So i get links like "www.mysite.de/articlename"

Now i wanted to create a page, where i can see the userinformations in the frontend.
So i want a link like "www.mysite.de/users/profile/admin" to be rewritten to "www.mysite.de/users/?user=admin"

I searched for more than 5 hours now, but dont get it working :(

This is what i tried

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^users/profile/(.)*$ users/?user=$1 [L]
# RewriteRule ^users/profile/(.)*$ index.php/pagename=users&user=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Btw: /users is a site i created before via the Wordpress Backend. If i use pagename=users i just get redirected to www.mysite.de/users :(

Any suggestions? Thanks for your help :)

Edit: Btw I tried the wp_directions from wordpress it self as well. No success
I added this to the functions.php

```
add_filter( 'rewrite_rules_array','my_insert_rewrite_rules' );
add_filter( 'query_vars','my_insert_query_vars' );
add_action( 'wp_loaded','my_flush_rules' );

// flush_rules() if our rules are not yet included
function my_flush_rules(){
    $rules = get_option( 'rewrite_rules' );

    if ( ! isset( $rules['(users)/(\d*)$'] ) ) {
        global $wp_rewrite;
        $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
    }
}

// Adding a new rule
function my_insert_rewrite_rules( $rules )
{
    $newrules = array();
    $newrules['(users)/(\d*)$'] = 'index.php?pagename=$matches[1]&id=$matches[2]';
    return $newrules + $rules;
}

// Adding the id var so that WP recognizes it
function my_insert_query_vars( $vars )
{
    array_push($vars, 'id');
    return $vars;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an error in your rule:

```
RewriteRule ^users/profile/(.)*$ users/?user=$1 [L]
```

The parentheses needs to enclose the `.*`:

```
RewriteRule ^users/profile/(.*)$ users/?user=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Oh, true story. THink this happened when i tired out some stuff. But this is not the solution :(

Comment: If this isn't the solution, why has it been marked as the correct answer?